# Where do I put these visible changes for them to display

Tags: c#

I have my code written like so:

```
private void radioSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pteriRadio.Checked) // Selecting avatar to be displayed from here on out.
    //This avatar will also be displayed on the game board.
    {
        pteriBox1.Visible = true;
        xweetokBox1.Visible = false;
        ixiBox1.Visible = false;
        label1.Text = ("Pteri Inventory");
        player1avatar = "pteri";
    }
    else if (xweetokRadio.Checked)
    {
        xweetokBox1.Visible = true;
        pteriBox1.Visible = false;
        ixiBox1.Visible = false;
        label1.Text = ("Xweetok Inventory");
        player1avatar = "xweetok";
    }
    else if (ixiRadio.Checked)
    {
        ixiBox1.Visible = true;
        pteriBox1.Visible = false;
        xweetokBox1.Visible = false;
        label1.Text = ("Ixi Inventory");
        player1avatar = "ixi";
    }
    characterSelectBox.Visible = false;
    radioSelectButton.Visible = false;
    characterSelectBox2.Visible = true;
    radioSelectButton2.Visible = true;
}
```

It  seems as though the visibility changes should display when I have it like this, with the changes within the button click but outside of the if statements (It doesn't matter what the user selects, once selected the option to select needs to disappear for that user.)Yet the visibility changes don't execute. What am I missing here?

If I nest the if-statements as suggested by a previous person, here's what I have:

```
    private void radioSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pteriRadio.Checked) // Selecting avatar to be displayed from here on out.
        //This avatar will also be displayed on the game board.
        {
            pteriBox1.Visible = true;
            xweetokBox1.Visible = false;
            ixiBox1.Visible = false;
            label1.Text = ("Pteri Inventory");
            player1avatar = "pteri";
            if (xweetokRadio.Checked)
            {
                xweetokBox1.Visible = true;
                pteriBox1.Visible = false;
                ixiBox1.Visible = false;
                label1.Text = ("Xweetok Inventory");
                player1avatar = "xweetok";

                if (ixiRadio.Checked)
                {
                    ixiBox1.Visible = true;
                    pteriBox1.Visible = false;
                    xweetokBox1.Visible = false;
                    label1.Text = ("Ixi Inventory");
                    player1avatar = "ixi";
                }
                characterSelectBox.Visible = false;
                radioSelectButton.Visible = false;
                characterSelectBox2.Visible = true;
                radioSelectButton2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, not only do the visible items not swap over, two of the character choices don't display.

Comment: Is this winform, asp, silverlight, wpf, or what?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the radio buttons here can be checked/unchecked together. I think you should use separate `if` statements for each condition instead of `else if`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invalidate.aspx) your form to make it redraw after you change the properties. Assuming the `radioSelectButton_Click` method is in the same form, calling `this.Invalidate()` at the end of the method should force the redraw.

Comment: This doesn't seem necessary in VS2010/.NET 4.0, either for a System.Windows.Form or for a System.Web.UI.Page.  What version/context are you thinking `Invalidate` would be required for

Comment: @tomfanning I'd added that before I realized *everything* has the same method profile...